# JS Image Cycler - Load in Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background, cycle

I've got a tricky little problem. I'm just starting out the design for a website with a cycling background image. At the minute it's working fine, although you can see the alternate background images loading with the first image which looks a little messy. I could pretty easily hide these images, but I feel a better solution would be to allow the first image to load before the others to speed up the page load. Unfortunately I cant work out how to incorporate this into my existing JS.

The beginnings of the site are [here](http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/) (it might be broken at some point, I'm still experimenting).

My current JS:

```
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('#background-cycler .active');
      var $next = ($('#background-cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background-cycler .active').next() : $('#background-cycler img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
      $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#background-cycler').fadeIn(1500);//fade the background back in once all the images are loaded
          // run every 7s
          setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background-cycler" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#background_cycler').hide();//hide the background while the images load, ready to fade in later
</script>

<img class="active" src="images/bg1.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/bg2.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/bg3.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/bg4.jpg" alt=""/>      
<img src="images/bg5.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!! :)

EDIT: The other problem I have is I need this on every page, but I'd rather not reload the images each time. Am I right in thinking the images will still be cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take at it:

http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/9TxED/

You hide the image element and only fade it in when the `onload` event is triggered.

And yes, all images will be cached by the browser throughout your site.

**HTML**

```
<div id="background-cycler" class="background-cycler">
    <img id="imgPrev" />
    <img id="imgNext" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background-cycler {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
}
.background-cycler img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var imgs = [
    'http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/images/bg1.jpg',
    'http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/images/bg2.jpg',
    'http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/images/bg3.jpg',
    'http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/images/bg4.jpg',
    'http://ravenstudio.co.uk/izzy/images/bg5.jpg']

var imgNext = document.getElementById("imgNext");
var imgPrev = document.getElementById("imgPrev");
var currentImg = -1;
var MAX_IMAGES = 5;
var CYCLE_DELAY = 2000;
var FADE_DELAY = 1500;

imgNext.onload = function () {
    // When finished loading:
    $(this).fadeIn(FADE_DELAY, function() {
        // When fadeIn ends:
        imgPrev.src = imgs[currentImg]; // Send current image to back
    }); // Fade in loaded image
    window.setTimeout('cycleImages()', CYCLE_DELAY + FADE_DELAY); // Set next cycle
};

cycleImages = function () {
    currentImg++;
    if (currentImg == MAX_IMAGES) currentImg = 0;
    imgNext.style.display = "none"; // Hide before loading
    imgNext.src = imgs[currentImg]; // Load new image. 
    // After imgNext finish loading, onload above will be called
}

cycleImages(); // Call the first cycle
```

Comment: This looks perfect in the JSFiddle! Unfortunately I cant seem to get this working. In chrome I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null" on line 15. I must confess my knowledge of JS is pretty limited.

Comment: everything must be inside a `$(function() {` ... `})` to be run only when the page is loaded